# Search proc_dir_entry by name

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to get pointer to proc_dir_entry by it's name (path).

I see in the [Linux source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.18/include/linux/proc_fs.h#L50) that proc entries are in double-linked list

```
struct proc_dir_entry {
    .....
    struct proc_dir_entry *next, *parent, *subdir;
```

So, I could probably loop over the list.

Is there any ready solution for it or should I do myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code exists but definitely not exported. See `xlate_proc_name` at `fs/proc/generic.c`.

Comment: Thanks! Found useful staff in generic.c

Comment: @adobriyan I created a dummy file using create_proc_read_entry, got the ->parent pointer then deleted it to get a pointer to the root proc_dir_entry. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks -